# Im trying to find a specific value in a multidimensional list. But when I try to find that specific value my function will return nothing

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, replit

So I am trying to search for the users specified movie rating in my list but every time I specify a rating to search for my function returns nothing.

For example: When it prompts me to enter a rating to find. I will type in "PG" and it will return nothing. Even though I know there are movies with a PG rating.

I think the problem may be either in my rating function or how I created my multidimensional list.

Below is my code. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

```
def getInput():
  try:
    inFile = open("movies.txt", 'r')
  except IOError:
    print("File cannot be found. Check Spelling.")
  else:
    return inFile.readlines()

def menu():
  L = getInput()
  for i in range(0, len(L)):
    L[i] = L[i].split('\n')
  while(True):
    print("\nWelcome to the movie finder!")
    print("\t1. Print the Movies alphabetically by name.")
    print("\t2. Print movies with a rating matching yours.")
    print("\t3. Print the movies by run time.")
    print("\t4. Find all movies with a run time less than your desired time.")
    print("\t5. Find all movies with a run time greater than your desired time.")
    print("Type -1 to quit.")
    opt = input("Input a number to start desired search: ")

    if (int(opt) == 1):
      alpha(L)
    elif (int(opt) == 2):
      rating(L)
    elif (int(opt) == 3):
      runTime(L)
    elif (int(opt) == 4):
      lessThan(L)
    elif (int(opt) == 5):
      greaterThan(L)
    elif (int(opt) == -1):
      break;
    else:
      print("Invalid Input")

def alpha(L):
  L.sort()
  print("\n",L)

def rating(L):
  userRate = str(input("Enter a rating to search for: "))
  for i in range(0, len(L)):
    for j in range(len(L[i])):
      if userRate == L[i][2]:
        print(L[i][0])

menu()
```

This is what L (my multidimensional list looks like)

```
[['"Detective Pikachu",104,PG', ''], ['"The Secret Life of Pets 2",86,PG', ''], ['"Deadpool 2",119,R', ''], ['"Godzilla: King of the Monsters",132,PG-13', ''], ['"A
vengers: Endgame",181,PG-13', ''], ['"The Lion King(1994)",88,G']]
```

Comment: "its' not working properly" is not allowed in a subject line, or question!  Be specific about the problem.  Are you getting an error?  On a quick read I notice that the last in sublist in `L` is different, with only one string element, not 2 like the others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line `L[i] = L[i].split('\n')` doesn't do what I think you want. Your rows of data are separated by commas, but you're splitting on the newline at the end. You probably want:

```
L[i] = L[i].strip('\n').split(',')
```

But rather than parsing the CSV file yourself, you may want to consider using [the `csv` module from the standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html), which will handle most of the details for you.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing particularly wrong with your code.
However, your `L`'s format is wrong.

```
['"Detective Pikachu",104,PG', '']
```

has only 2 elements in it.
Element `0` is `"Detective Pikachu",104,PG`
Element `1` is .

You should either fix the way your `getInput()` parses the `movies.txt` or change your functions to read the `L`.

Also, you should `close()` your file after usage.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I didn't realize that the elements in my list were messed up. I was wondering if I could possibly .remove() each Element 1 in my lists?

Comment: @SwerveOnEm My advice is that you should parse your `movies.txt` correctly first instead of handling it in your output functions. The reason for this is to make your code reusable. Study what your `movies.txt` structure is like first, then adapt your `getInput()` to parse it correctly into the format you want.